# Non-capturing group still selecting meta escape

Tags: regex, pcre

I am using pcre regex and want to select the final `}` after `\begin{pmatrix}` ... `}` to replace it with `\end{pmatrix}`.

The context is that I am making an auto converter from `\bmx{...}` to `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` for LaTeX and this is the last step in my procedure.

I have tried

```php
(?<=\\begin{pmatrix})(?:(.*?)(?=}))(.)
```

It utilizes a positive lookbehind and a non-capturing group to help me find the `}` after the meat of the matrix (the ... before).

Why is the non-capturing group still capturing? It is preventing me from finishing my project.

Here is a link to the regex: https://regex101.com/r/FIUBMt/1

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about the purpose of non-capturing groups (and capturing ones for that matter). Try replacing `(\\begin{pmatrix}[^}]*)}` with `\1\\end{pmatrix}`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/DzkqOR/1).

Comment: To elaborate, what gets matched by a non-capturing group is _not_ excluded from the final match. The reason it's called "non-capturing" is because it doesn't capture something into a numbered/named group that can be accessed separately. A capturing group, on the other hand, does do that.

Comment: Your regex is equal to `(?<=\\begin{pmatrix})(.*?)(})`

Answer (score 0):

According to your current regex logic the fix will be

```php
\\begin{pmatrix}[^}]*\K}
```

See the regex demo.

*Details*:

- `\\begin{pmatrix}` - a `\\begin{pmatrix}` string
- `[^}]*` - zero or more chars other than `}`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the currently matched text from the match value
- `}` - the only `}` that gets matched and consumed.